# Pass unicode instead of string from robot framework to python

Tags: python, unicode, robotframework, python-2.x

I have a robot framework file where I am calling a python function and passing it an argument. I want to pass the argument to python as a Unicode, but it keeps getting passed as the string.

Function is

```
def assert_my_test( var1, var3=[]):
  print "var1" #this i want in unicode, unicode(var1) doesnt help
  f=gzip.open("myfile.gzip")
  lines=f.readlines()

  if any(unicode(var1) in unicode(s) for s in lines):
       print "found our line"
```

Robot is

```
========================  =====================  ======================= 
Test Case                 Action                 Argument
========================  =====================  ======================= 
test1                     myprog.assert_my_test  \x01\x02\x03
```

Output is x01x02x03 instead of 
u"x01x02x03"

Any ideas how to pass Unicode properly? Really appreciated.

I have tried passing "Unicode(var1) to the function definition but that results in an error.

Complete variable i am trying to pass is -

```
\x01\x02\x03html&h=250&slotname5&adk=1204670.0&url=htt||1|0Ft2qy|4CX000||||17.022qy^A0C5vZBmjiK^ABusiness^DPersonalFin-0^A^A^Afalse^Afalse^A^A^A^A^A^A^A^A^A0^A0^A0^A0^A^A^A1^A^A^A^A1^A^A^A^A6284035007053575^A^A^Aen^A^Ab1cc^A^A8281671^Aalias_type^DDX^Calias_id^D4CXDxrs315^C"
```

I want to find if this variable exists in the file.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] and explain what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you print a value, naturally you get the printable representation of that value.

I have no idea why you would want this, but you can get your desired output by calling `repr()`:

```
print repr(var1)
```

(Also, not related to your problem, but don't use a list as a default argument: see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument) as to why.)

**Edit** So I'm still not entirely sure what you are trying to do, but I *think* what is going on is that you have a raw string consisting of slashes, Xs and digits, not bytes. You can convert that to unicode by decoding it using the "unicode-escape" codec:

```
var1 = r'\x01\x02\x03'
decoded = var1.decode('unicode-escape')  # result: u'\x01\x02\x03'
```

Comment: Well I am trying to compare it after, but in the comparison it seems that I am trying to compare a unicode with a non unicode string so its not working.  I tried printing with repr() and the result seems to be the same. Thanks for the default argument link though.

Comment: You should show the code you are actually having problems with, then. It's perfectly possible to compare unicode with bytestrings in Python 2.

Comment: I think you need to show what data you are passing in, and how.